# Python - Skip to next line when opening file and looping each line

Tags: python

How do you skip to the next lines of a file being looped line by line.  This code below is skipping lines for the total count in the 2nd loop, I want it to skip the line 1 by 1 for the desired count so I can pull the right information from the file.

```
f = open("someTXT", "r")

lines = iter(f.readlines())

for line in lines:
    thisLine = line.split(',')
    if len(thisLine) > 3:
        count = thisLine[4]
        for i in range(1,int(count)):
            next(lines)
            print(line)
```

Comment: you want to skip the first "n" lines?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a bit of code review. Not sure what you're asking though.

Use the context manager to open files:

```
with open("someTXT", 'rU') as f: # Universal newline flag, best practice

    # lines = iter(f) # no need for this, my_file is an iterator
    container = [] #   use a container to hold your lines
    for line in f:
        test = test_for_correct_lines(line) # return True if keep and print
        if test:
            container.append(line)

# join the lines you want to keep with a newline and print them
print('\n'.join(container))
```